# Ray-plane intersection point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Ray has origin $o$ and direction $\vec{d}$. Any point on it can be defined as
$r(t) = o + t.\vec{d}$.
Now a plane has the equation $p \cdot \vec{n} - D = 0$, where D is the distance from the origin to the plane, $\vec{n}$ is a normal vector of the plane. I don't know what $p$ is, I tried on paper and actually managed to conclude that a plane can be defined only by $\vec{n}$ and D (D would limit all the distances to the plane and will form a sphere. If we have the normal, we can just extend the plane and see where it does intersect that sphere.)
To find the intersection of ray and plane, I am told to plug the ray: 
$(o + t.\vec{d}) \cdot \vec{n} - D =0$ and thus find $t=(D - o \cdot \vec{n}) / (\vec{d} \cdot \vec{n})$. What is $t$ and what is $p$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ray Plane Intersection Calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247264/ray-plane-intersection-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

p is a vector and t is the parameter (a real number) of the line Equation, you can obtain the point by using $ r(t) = o + t.\vec{d}$

Given any A on the plane, and the normal vector $\vec{n}$, and p presents the point on the plane, then the plane Equation can be written as :

$ (p - A) \cdot \vec{n} = 0 $ where (p - A) means all the vector perpendicular to $\vec{n}$

now you can get $ p \cdot \vec{n} - D = 0 $ where $ D = A \cdot \vec{n} $

t is the parameter (a real number) of the line Equation,